# Algorithm and data representation to query point density

Tags: algorithm, spatial, data-representation

If I have a set of points on a 2D plane (x, y) and I want to be able to find the place on that plane where the points are most densely clustered, what algorithm could I use and what would be an appropriate way to store those data points (e.g. some form of tree maybe?).  I understand that 'most dense' could probably be calculated in different ways but I'm open to various interpretations (e.g. most points within a given radius).

I'd like to query and adjust the points that are on the plane in real-time: I'll happily take a hit on the time it takes to add and remove points as long as the lookup time is fast.

And forgive me, maybe my question is too vague.  If so, I'd welcome pointers to how you can generally query a 'density map' (and whether that is the right term?).

Comment: Have you tried the search function with "clustering" ?

Comment: Thanks, I have since been directed to cluster analysis algorithms so I'm busy trying to dig my way through the many options.